# After doing npm install in the ready project it cause this error on simulator

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm-install, node-modules, expo

[Unable to resolve module....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfEKy.png)

I try the solution which it offers in the bellow of image but it doesn't solve. When i download project node_modules folder and add in the project it works perfectly. While I need instead of downloading and adding so large folder there to use just npm install. How can this trouble be solved? Project from scratch was built by expo.

Comment: Try with `react-native init projectname`. This will create project without expo

Comment: yes but ready project itself was built with expo.